# Measure fluid speed by using a hot plate

Tags: flow, sensor

I would like to figure out whether it is possible to measure the speed of a fluid by letting it flow across a hot plate. I was thinking about using the formulas for forced convection. The plate is heated up by electricity. Therefor I know how much energy I put into the plate in the form of heat (assuming that all electrical energy that is lost in the plate is converted into heat).

I assume that I know all the fluid properties and that the flow is laminar, therefor I will know the Reynolds number as a function of $V$, the speed of the fluid. With that I calculate the average Nusselt number which then also will become a function of $V$. With the average Nusselt number I can calculate the heat transfer coefficient $h$ and fill that in for $Q$. The function for $Q$ is:

$$Q=h*A*(Tp-Te)\tag{1}$$

Filling in the variables gives me the following formula:

$$Q=0.664*((\rho*V*L)/\mu)^{1/2}*Pr^{1/3}*K*W*(Tp-Te)\tag{2}$$

$\rho$, $L$ (length of the plate), $\mu$, $Pr$, $K$ and $W$ (width of the plate) are known. I also assume that I know the temperature of the fluid, $Te$.

My unknowns are $Q$, $V$ (speed of the fluid) and $Tp$ (temperature of the plate). I know that I heat the plate up with electricity. Therefor $Q$ is dependent on the electrical energy.

$$Q=I^2*R=I*U\tag{3}$$

Combining everything results in the following formula:

$$I*U=0.664*((\rho*V*L/\mu)^{1/2}*Pr^{1/3}*K*W*(Tp-Te)\tag{4}$$

And from here on I don't really know how to continue. I can control two things, $I$ and $U$. That leaves me with the unknowns $Tp$ and $V$. $V$ is the variable that I want to measure so I need to figure out what $Tp$ is.

Is it possible what I am trying to do or am I overseeing something? Also if this is correct, how should I continue? Do I have to measure $Tp$ in a test setup where $V$ is known in order to calibrate the sensor. I also try to figure out what happens if $V$ changes, what that does to the other variables.

Help would be much appreciated. If my explaining is vague, please let me know and I will try to clarify myself better.

Comment: Have you heard of a [hot wire anemometer](https://circuitglobe.com/hot-wire-anemometer.html)? It sounds like that's what you're trying to replicate, that might send you down the right directions.

Comment: Calibration will be necessary. It does not make sense to rely on calculations.

Comment: is the whole stream passing through your apparatus? or does your apparatus sit at the periphery and measure the speed there?  is the fliud conductive and non magnetic- MHD works fairly well for boat speedometers.

Comment: @tpg2114 I am indeed trying to replicate a hot wire anemometer. I am trying to figure out the working principle and seeing if I can apply it to fluid passing one side of a plate instead of a wire that is in the middle of the stream.

Comment: @Jasen The whole stream is going through a square shaped tube. I want to use one of the sides of the square shaped tube as the heated plate. I am assuming the fluid is conductive and non magnetic.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my answer. The resistance $R$ of my plate is defined as following.

$$R=R_f(1+\alpha*(T_p-T_r)\tag{1}$$

I combined this with my other formula.

$$I^2*R=0.664*((\rho*V*L/\mu)^{1/2}*Pr^{1/3}*K*W*(T_p-T_e)\tag{2}$$

The combined rearranged result is as following.

$$V=\frac{\mu}{\rho*L}*\left(\frac{I^2*R_r*(1+\alpha*(T_p-T_r))}{0.664
    *Pr^{1/3}*K*W*(T_p-T_e)}\right)^2\tag{3}$$

I think this formula covers what I wanted to know.